# Varying Unity injection by HttpRoute in C# Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, unity-container, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am working on a Web API service to a datastore with common methods like GetAll, GetById, Search, Insert, Update, and so on.

I have the following code in the configuration:

```
    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DataApiRoute",
        routeTemplate: "api/"+ IocConfig.Name() +"/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new {
            id = RouteParameter.Optional,
            controller = "DataApi"
        }
    );

    // IOC
    var container = new UnityContainer();
    container.RegisterInstance<IData>(IocConfig.RegisterThisInstance());
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
```

The model has been separated to a different Project.

As you can see, I am pulling the model instance and the name for the service in from a static config (IocConfig) in the model project. So now my controller project doesn't know anything about the model except for IData and IocConfig.

So now I have a fixed controller project that can have different models plugged into it, and it doesn't have to change as long as those models match IData and publish the IocConfig. All good.

But I want to now allow this system to handle multiple models. I can easily loop over a string[] for MapHttpRoute and generate those. I can provide instances for the RegisterInstance to register. **But how do I vary those by route? I want it so the Product model gets injected for /api/product/ route but the Customer model gets injected for the /api/customer/ route.**

It all boils down the to IData in this line

```
container.RegisterInstance<IData>(IocConfig.RegisterThisInstance());
```

...but I think I am having a problem visualising how this can work, if at all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't decided whether or not I like this approach, but it should work.  You are basically giving your container named instances that can be referenced later, and injecting a factory into each controller instead of the instance itself.

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterInstance<IData>("Product", myProductInstance); 
container.RegisterInstance<IData>("Customer", myCustomerInstance);

container.RegisterType<Func<string, IData>>(
    new InjectionFactory(c => new Func<string, IData>(name => c.Resolve<IData>(name)))
);
```

ProductController.cs

```
private IData _model;
public ProductController(Func<string, IData> factory)
{
    _model = factory("Product");
}
```

CustomerController.cs

```
private IData _model;
public CustomerController(Func<string, IData> factory)
{
    _model = factory("Customer");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Borophyll. Your code led me to a better understanding of how this works and I was trying to solve the problem in the wrong place.

I wanted to use the one controller... but that controller is automatically created once by web api. So I can't inject multiple models that way. I was visualizing it wrong.

The solution was actually simple. Inject a collection of model instances once to the controller.

In the IocConfig:

```
public static Dictionary<string, IData> RegisterTheseInstances()
{
    return new Dictionary<string, IData>()
    {
        { "customer", new Customer() },
        { "test",  new Test() }
    };
}
```

In the controller:

```
private Dictionary<string, IData> Data;

[InjectionConstructor]
public DataApiController(Dictionary<string, IData> data)
{
    Data = data;
}
```

And the routing, ioc config simplified now to this:

```
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DataApiRoute",
            routeTemplate: "api/{model}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new
            {
                id = RouteParameter.Optional,
                controller = "DataApi"
            }
        );

        // IOC
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterInstance(IocConfig.RegisterTheseInstances());
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
```

Note that the controller is hardcoded to "DataApi" but there is a /model/ route value in its place.

Then I differentiate between the models on each call by using the model value passed to the method:

```
[HttpGet]
public object Search(string id, string model)
{
    return Data[model].Search(id);
}
```

Hey presto.

Need to add some checks to handle if the model requested exists or not but it works as of now.